# Where should I place Bug tracker info in question I asked

Tags: discussion

I was curious if there is a correct place to put Bug tracker info of a question that I asked. For example ([see here for question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25628127/issue-with-custom-renderer-and-adding-icons-to-toolbaritems-navigationitem-with)) I encountered an issue that I believed was a bug in a third party software. I asked a question on Stack Overflow hoping for answer/workaround, and after contacting the third party software support it was confirmed it was a bug in their code base. A bug tracker was created for the issue, so my question is should I place the bug tracker info in the comments or in an answer to the question. Is one preferred over the other?

Comment: I'd edit the question to include that information in, or add a comment - it doesn't answer your question if you're looking for a workaround, so avoid doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your question is seeking an *explanation* of the behavior, then an answer is the appropriate place to link to the bug in the official bug tracker database. Later, if and when the bug is fixed, that answer can be updated to include the relevant information about which version(s) contain the fix or what you need to do to obtain the official fix.

If your question is searching for a *workaround* for the bug, then it is not really appropriate to post the link to the bug tracker database as an answer. It is not an answer. You don't really care that the bug has been reported or that the developer is aware of it—you're still having the problem, and so will everyone in the future who uses the same version of the software (e.g., because they are unable to update to the latest version).

It's still useful information, though, so posting it in a comment or editing it into the question itself would be fine. Something like:

> This bug [has now been officially reported](http://www.example.com/), but I am looking for a workaround.

or

> This [has been confirmed](http://www.example.com/) as a bug in the framework, but I am still looking for a workaround.

at the bottom of the question. The question will have already set out your specific requirements.